# JSON returning Bad request - postcodes.io

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have this method:

```
import requests
import json

data = {  
    "postcodes" : ["AL1 2RJ", "AL9 5JP", "BN14 9GB", "BN16 3RT", "BN23 6QD", "BN3 7PN", "BN9 0AG", "BR5 3RP", "CM2 6XE","CM20 2SX","CR0 4NX","CT1 1DX",
    "CT1 3TQ", "CT10 2RQ", "CT16 3PS", "CT19 5SY", "DA1 4LD", "DA11 0DQ", "E4 8JA", "E6 6LG", "EN1 1TH", "EN9 1BY", "GU14 7QL", "GU19 5DG", "GU22 8BD",
    "GU34 2QS","GU7 1DR", "GU9 9QJ", "HA4 0LN", "HP11 1FY", "HP20 1DH", "HP3 9AA", "IG2 6BE", "KT12 2SS", "KT14 7NP", "LU1 3JH", "LU5 4XZ",
    "ME10 2XD", "ME20 7TP", "ME5 9SQ", "ME8 0PU", "MK1 1BN", "MK18 1TB", "N11 3PW", "NW1 9EX", "NW9 7TH", "PO19 7YH", "PO22 9NF", "PO3 5LZ",
    "PO9 1ND", "RG12 1EN", "RG2 0HB", "RG22 4TT", "RG30 1PR", "RG40 2NU", "RG41 5HH", "RH1 6QL", "RH11 7ST", "RH12 1HR", "RH15 9QT", "RH19 1QL",
    "RM20 3LP", "RM7 0AN", "RM9 6SJ", "SE1 5BA", "SE10 8DA", "SE26 4PU", "SE28 8RD", "SE7 7TZ", "SE9 5LT", "SG13 7RQ", "SL1 4XB", "SL6 1AY",
    "SS1 1PA", "SS13 3BY", "SS14 3AF", "SS2 6FW", "SS67UP", "SW11 3RX", "SW17 0BW", "SW20 0JQ", "TN14 5EW", "TN2 3FB", "TN23 7DH", "TN37 7PB",
    "TN40 2JS", "TW13 4EX", "TW8 8JW", "TW9 1YB", "UB4 0TU", "UB6 0UW", "UB8 2TE", "WD17 2SF", "WD6 4PR"]
    }

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
resp = requests.post('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/', data=data, headers=headers)
print(resp.json())
```

I run this `python myscript.py < myfile.json`

```
{'status': 400, 'error': 'Invalid JSON submitted. You need to submit a JSON object with an array of postcodes or geolocation objects. Also ensure that Content-Type is set to application/json'}
```

But the request seems to be fine, this is what the `postcodes.io` doc says:

```
Bulk Postcode Lookup

Accepts a JSON object containing an array of postcodes. Returns a list of matching postcodes and respective available data.

Be sure to submit JSON requests setting Content-Type to application/json

Accepts up to 100 postcodes.

POST
https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes

Post Data

This method requires a JSON object containing an array of postcodes to be posted, e.g.

{  
  "postcodes" : ["PR3 0SG", "M45 6GN", "EX165BL"]
}
```

[This is the doc page](https://postcodes.io/docs)

The query seems to be fine, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `json=data` instead of `data=data` so it sets the correct content-type ?

Comment: Haha lol, that was it, Thank You, you can put this as an answer if You please :)

Comment: I think it's probably a duplicate... I've certainly seen it come up a few times... Can I find one though (*sigh*)... fairly sure I've seen a decent one about when to use data vs json and why they differ...

Comment: Hmmm, right, it's ok, Thank You very much :)

Comment: Just no a side note... is the data from postcodes.io reasonably okay? I know I've played with it and I'm sure it misses out some addresses that I'm sure are present on PAF...

Comment: It is reasonably okay, it just returns a very "dirty" json, I mean, it's a big one liner, which I'm looking to beautify somehow, I'm gonna post a question for that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to replace `data=data` with `json=data`. So that it can be verify against `content-type=application/json`.

```
resp = requests.post('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/', json=data, headers=headers)
```

it will work.

Answer (score 1):

So I had pretty similar problem, and I was struggling to transform a dataframe column into a list then into a json object. The solution might be pretty obvious, but I got lost in json.dumps() and that is not the solution. The following worked:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

#imagine you have a csv, excel where you have the postcodes
create_sample={'Postcode': ['OL67UB', 'AB101QS']} 
df_postcodes=pd.DataFrame(create_sample)

list_postcodes=list(df_postcodes['Postcode'])

data = {  
        "postcodes" : list_postcodes
      }

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
resp = requests.post('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/', json=data, headers=headers)
print(resp.json())
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the bulk form can only handle 100 postcodes, so iterating thru each by each is more meaningful if you have thousands.